# Is there a way to find when an instance was spawned and other details in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

With an Instance ID, can the details of the instance can be read from the google console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the `startTime` of an instance in the Google Cloud Console click on the `Navigation Menu > App Engine > Instances`. Select the service you are interested on and below the graphic there will be displayed a table with the `startTime` of each instance.

Or you can run the following command:

`gcloud app instances describe <INSTANCE_ID> -s=<SERVICE> -v=<VERSION> | grep startTime`

**EDIT**:

In case the instances no longer exists you can use this filter in the Google Cloud Stackdriver Logging Console:

```
resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.module_id="SERVICE"
resource.labels.version_id="VERSION"
protoPayload.instanceId="INSTANCE_ID"
```

The timestamp of the first entry will roughly coincide with the `StartTime` of the instance.